# How can I check if a php array's keys all have values and none are blank or unset

Tags: php

I create a php array on the fly like below in php, which is then `json_encoded` and sent back to the `ajax` script that requested it.

```
$myarr['key_a'] = 'a';
$myarr['key_b'] = 'b';
$myarr['key_c'] = 'c';
```

Before I do the json_encode, since the values for this come from a database, is there someway I can check if all values are set and none are blank or unset without having to check each key individually?

Comment: Why not check whilst building the array?

Comment: You can try with [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Use loops if you know it...

Answer (score 15):

```
if (count($myarr) != count(array_filter($myarr))) {
    // Oops, empty values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//$arr is your array contains values from database
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
  if(trim($val) != ''){
    $newArr[$key] = $val;
  }
}
json_encode($newArr);
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what the OP meant by `"without having to check each key individually"`. The answer is correct though.

Comment: This doesn't check whether there are any empty values, it just removes them from the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go running around and checking each key individually (by using `foreach`), you should be making sure that the generated array is already checked on creation.

Adding a `if(empty($value)) { // Do stuff }` might fix your problems at its core.